# PHP curl and DOM to get the content of the tables and tds

Tags: javascript, php, parsing, curl, dom

[image]I am trying to make a website that connects to a catalogue of car parts and getting the data of a selected vehicle model.

I have to outpunt in the page all the tables that i get and pick the vehicle part code for example "PA7458" and put it in an array.But im a blocked, i'm not good with CURL and parsing in general.

If is there any other solution rather than using curl, feel free to tell me it!
Thanks for help!! :)

Here is my code:

```php
<?php
  $curl3 = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($curl3, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.sogefifilterdivision.com/catalogues/FO/scripts/cat_rech_vehicules.php?zone=FR&catalogue=CPF&lang=IT&vehicule_marque=FIAT&vehicule_modele=Punto+Evo+1.3+Multijet+16V");
  curl_setopt($curl3, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($curl3, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
  $str = curl_exec($curl3);
  curl_close($curl3);

  $dom = new DOMDocument();
  $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
  @$dom->loadHTML($str);

  $tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');

  echo "Found : ".$tables->length. " items";

  $i = 0;
  $contenuto="";
  while($table = $tables->item($i++))
  {
    $contenuto=$dom->saveHTML($table);

    if (strpos($contenuto, 'Motore') !== false) {
        // echo "<div class='row'>";
        echo "<br><br><div class='col-md-6' style='border:1px solid red;'>";
    }

    if (strpos($contenuto, 'Filtro') !== false || strpos($contenuto, 'Olio') !== false || strpos($contenuto, 'Gasolio') !== false || strpos($contenuto, 'Aria') !== false) {
        echo "<div class='col-md-6' style='border:1px solid black;'>";
    }

    $anchor = $table->nodeValue;
    echo "<td>".$contenuto."</td>";

    if (strpos($contenuto, 'Filtro') !== false || strpos($contenuto, 'Olio') !== false || strpos($contenuto, 'Gasolio') !== false || strpos($contenuto, 'Aria') !== false) {
        echo "</div>";
    }

    if (strpos($contenuto, 'Motore') !== false) {
        echo "</div>";
    }
  }
?>
```

This is the output, but i want to have a table with rows and columns and edit the anchors.

//simple html dom

```html
i am here now, but how i can buld a table?  include('simple_html_dom.php');


$curl3 = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl3, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.sogefifilterdivision.com/catalogues/FO/scripts/cat_rech_vehicules.php?zone=FR&catalogue=CPF&lang=IT&vehicule_marque=FIAT&vehicule_modele=Punto+Evo+1.3+Multijet+16V");
curl_setopt($curl3, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl3, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);

$html = str_get_html(curl_exec($curl3));

foreach($html->find('table tr td') as $e){
    $arr[] = trim($e->innertext);
  }



 for ($i=0; $i < COUNT($arr) ; $i++) {
   echo $arr[$i].": ".$arr[$i+1]."<br>";
   $i++;
 }
```

OUTPUT ON THE PAGE:
Motore : 199A9.000 (Euro4) 
 Potenza : 55KW(75PS/HP) 
 Cilindrata : 1248 
 Inizio : 10/09 
 Fine commercializzazione : 02/12 
Filtro: Abbreviazioni
CPF: Istruzioni
 Aria  :
 PA7506 :
 Filtro abitacolo  :
 PC8170 :
 Filtro abitacolo  :   anti-odore 
 PCK8194 :
 Gasolio  :
 FP5760HWS :
 Olio  :   montaggio PURFLUX 
 FA5677ECO :
 Olio  :   montaggio UFI 
 FA5766ECO :
 Motore : 199A3.000 
 Potenza : 66KW(90PS/HP) 
 Cilindrata : 1248 
 Inizio : 10/09 
 Fine commercializzazione : 02/12 
Filtro: Abbreviazioni
CPF: Istruzioni
 Aria  :
 PA7701 :
 Filtro abitacolo  :
 PC8170 :
 Filtro abitacolo  :   anti-odore 
 PCK8194 :
 Gasolio  :
 FP5759HWS :
 Olio  :   Euro 5
 FA5919ECO :
 Olio  :   Euro 4 montaggio PURFLUX 
 FA5677ECO :
 Olio  :   Euro 4 montaggio UFI 
 FA5766ECO :
 Motore : 199B1.000 
 Potenza : 70KW(95PS/HP) 
 Cilindrata : 1248 
 Inizio : 10/09 
 Fine commercializzazione : 02/12 
Filtro: Abbreviazioni
CPF: Istruzioni
 Aria  :
 PA7701 :
 Filtro abitacolo  :
 PC8170 :
 Filtro abitacolo  :   anti-odore 
 PCK8194 :
 Gasolio  :
 FP5759HWS :
 Olio  :   Euro 5
 FA5919ECO :
 Motore : 199A9.000 (Euro5) 
 Potenza : 55KW(75PS/HP) 
 Cilindrata : 1248 
 Inizio : 10/09 
 Fine commercializzazione :
Filtro: Abbreviazioni
CPF: Istruzioni
 Aria  :
 PA7701 :
 Filtro abitacolo  :
 PC8170 :
 Filtro abitacolo  :   anti-odore 
 PCK8194 :
 Gasolio  :
 FP5759HWS :
 Olio  :
 FA5919ECO :

---

```html
echo "<table style='border:1px solid black;'>";
  for ($i=0; $i < COUNT($arr) ; $i++) {

   //echo $arr[$i].": ".$arr[$i+1]."<br>";
   echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$arr[$i]."</td>";
   echo "</tr>";

   $i++;
  }
  echo "</table>";
```

[image]

Comment: What is the desired output/result?  What is the actual output/result?  What debugging have you done?  Are you getting errors?  If so, what are they?  Just saying "this isn't working" isn't a question.

Comment: I have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

if you would use the "html dom parser" it will be much easier , Curl will return a string containing the HTML right, Just use [the quick start sample](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

```
$html = str_get_html(curl_exec($ch));
```

---

try the following :

```
foreach($html->find('.tabtxtgras') as $key => $e){
    $arr[] = trim($e->innertext);
    $arr2[] = trim($html->find('.tabtxt')[$key]->innertext);
  }

echo "<table style='border:1px solid black;'>";
  for ($i=0; $i < COUNT($arr) ; $i++) {

   //echo $arr[$i].": ".$arr[$i+1]."<br>";
   echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$arr[$i]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$arr2[$i]."</td>";
   echo "</tr>";

   $i++;
  }
  echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Yes, but i try and it sas  Warning: file_get_contents(): stream does not support seeking in C:\xampp\htdocs\template\simple_html_dom.php on line 75

Warning: file_get_contents(): Failed to seek to position -1 in the stream in C:\xampp\htdocs\template\simple_html_dom.php on line 75

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function find() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\template\home-area.php:849 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\template\home-area.php on line 849

Comment: im assuming you are using php 7.1, 
Change $offset = -1 by $offset = 0 in the simple_html_dom.php file

Comment: I have updated the question, see the simple html dom

Comment: the website is this one: http://www.sogefifilterdivision.com/catalogues/FO/scripts/cat_rech_vehicules.php?zone=FR&catalogue=CPF&lang=IT&vehicule_marque=FIAT&vehicule_modele=Punto+Evo+1.3+Multijet+16V   Do you think i can get all the values and format them in similar tables changing hrefs of avery anchor???

Comment: well good job @Medy can you show us the output of this line  echo $arr[$i].": ".$arr[$i+1]."<br>";
 and sure yes you can loop over all tables as each table exists inside a dev with the same class name

Comment: Awesome i hope i helped, you can now 
get all the values and format them in similar tables changing hrefs of every anchor  also check the Docs here it has a lot of nice helpful methods http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_api.htm

Comment: Can you post some code on how you can make a table with this data?I have added the output that i get

Comment: @Medy i updated my answer, please check the concept of the new update , i tried on my local machine and it works perfectly